# Authentication service

Tags: c#, sql, service

I need to create an authorization system for my C# application that works like this: user enters login data, the password is being converted to MD5, sent to server where a special service looks for a login, gets its password and converts to MD5. Than these MD's are compared and an answer is sent back. Does anyone have an example of the service described above or ideas?

Comment: Do you only need the server for authentication?  A WCF service using ASP.NET authentication might serve you well with this, but may be overkill if you have nothing else to do on the server end.

Comment: Yes, I need only a Windows service for authentication

Comment: Perhaps a customer [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) is in order? _(See [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx))_

Comment: Why you need a window service for this.? WCF service can do it for you. In fact you can create a class library and create a method inside it, that will work as well unless you really need a service which will be used by multiple applications

Comment: 2Kunal: There are many simple ways to create an authentication with SQL and C#. So the first one I thought about is to convert password to MD5 locally, then make a selection in a remote DB by the login, get the password and compare the pair also locally. But there's a huge problem: if the DB is stolen I won't restore the passwords from hash. So the only way I see is to keep password "as is" and to convert user's input on the server. This could be done with a service

Comment: MD5 is not a way to keep a secret

Answer (score 0):

1) Remember to add some salt before making a hash (md5).

2) Maybe try switching to something else than md5 e.g., sha1.

3) Dependent on the size of the service you may try to complicate system a little by the cost of performance. For example first initiate connection and get some kind of token (random number/phrase/etc.) from the server. Then calculate the md5 of something like md5(md5(salt+pass)+token), and send it to the server. The reason for the twice application of md5 is that you should not store users passwords in a not hashed form. At least I would not do so.

Comment: Do you have any working example of such application? I'm trying to work with services for the 1st time. So no practice behind to realize what you've described

Comment: Sorry, but as for now I do not.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Use SSL/TLS and a server certificate and make sure that the correct certificate is used in the client.
2. Use digest authentication on top of that. The problem is that you will need to store a HA1 hash in your database or the passwords in clear text (or be able to decrypt the stored passwords) to be able to generate a HA1 hash. A HA1 hash is `Md5(userName + ":" + realm + ":" + password)` where realm is the domain.
3. You can use my webserver (LGPL) in your windows service to create the authentication. http://webserver.codeplex.com. It supports both HTTPS and Digest authentication.

Comment: Do you think that storing password as a clear text is a good idea?

Comment: No, and I never stated that I did either. It sounded as the database already exists, hence the different solution examples.